# Firebase android jars documentation/javadoc in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, javadoc, android-studio-2.1

I'm trying to view Firebase's Javadoc API for Android on Android studio. I found the javadoc on the internet. For example: [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference).

The problem is that I don't see an option to do it in Android Studio. See screenshot.

I have an option to attach the source code of firebase, but can't find it on the web.

**How do I view Firebase's javadoc in Android Studio?** Thanks.

[image]

Comment: There's an closed issue regarding automatic attaching source code to jars and the javadoc equivalent was merged to it, but it doesn't discuss manually attaching javadoc. Issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59220

Comment: Perhaps `Firebase` guys/gals have't attached a javadoc reference to the bytecode jar in order to have automatically imported?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase source is not available to public, so all you'll get is the obfuscated version until they decide to release the source code.

UPDATE: You can find the reference on https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/packages , once again i have no info about the release of javadocs to include.

Comment: My question relates to the javadoc. Not source code. Thank you anyways.

Comment: But Javadoc somehow IS sourcecode since it is tied together in the same file.